# Convert elapsed time between epoch time and current moment to ISO 8601 duration with Java

Tags: java, datetime, duration, epoch

I have milliseconds since 1970 january 1 UTC (Epoch time).

```
1512431637067
```

I need to convert this to something like (ISO-8601 duration). This will be based off current today's date.

```
P5M4D
```

Any idea how to do this in a simple way using java code?

Comment: Idea: convert the seconds in a date-timestamp. Create a new timestamp of the first, same date, but with 00:00:00. Then compute the difference and convert it in the desired ISO-format.

Comment: Can you clarify how "P5M4D" (five months and four days) is related to the rest of your question (because 1512431637067 is certainly a much bigger duration)?

Comment: It seems the number given is actually *milliseconds* since 1970.

Comment: “based off current today's date”, does that mean you want the length of time between that epoch time and the time now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Guernsey");  // Specify a time zone by proper name `Contintent/Region`, never by 3-4 letter codes such as `PST`, `CST`, or `IST`.
LocalDate then =                             // Represent a date-only value, without time zone and without time-of-day.
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(1_512_431_637_067L) // Parse your number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z as a value in UTC.
           .atZone(zone)                     // Adjust from UTC to some other zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time. Returns a `ZonedDateTime`.  
           .toLocalDate();                   // Extract a date-only value.
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);       // Get the current date as seen in the wall-clock time in use by the people of a particular region.
Period diff = Period.between(then, today);   // Determine the number of years-months-days elapsed.
System.out.println(diff);                    // Generate a String is standard ISO 8601 format: `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`.
```

Output when running just now is exactly what you asked for:

> P5M4D

The result is time zone dependent. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

Therefore please substitute your desired time zone if it didn’t happen to be `Europe/Guernsey`. Use [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC) and [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class if you want the calculation to happen in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

For example running that code above for `Europe/Guernsey` results in P5M4D, while switching to `Europe/Moscow` results in P5M3D, for a difference of one day depending on which zone you specify.

```
Period.between(then, LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow")))
```

Output on the day the question was asked would have been:

> P5M3D

For a duration that includes units larger than a day you need to use the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class of `java.time` The [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class is for smaller units, days-hours-minutes-seconds-nanoseconds.

Comment: The problem with this is that it discards the time of day from both arguments. Thus, it fails to give the correct period modulo days. I.e. yesterday 9am to tomorrow 10am is 2 days, but yesterday 9am to tomorrow 8am is 1 day, as it's not quite 2 days until 9am. Your solution gives 2 days for both scenarios.

Comment: Your description of the behaviour of my code is correct, @DodgyCodeException. Whether this is a problem or it is correct depends on what you want. :-) According to what you say is correct, we should only get P5M3D from the asker’s data, but P5M4D was asked for. Also the asker said “current today's date”, not “current time”.

Comment: True. But now your solution is time-zone-dependent. For example, if you just replace "Europe/Guernsey" with "Europe/Moscow", you'll get P5M3D. Whether the answer should depend on time zone or not is up to the OP, but I thought I'd just point it out.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Actually, such calculation is *always* dependent on time zone. The issue is whether the programmer is careful enough to explicitly handle the zone rather than implicitly/ignorantly ignore the issue. But I'm glad you raised the point as it is vitally important. I edited the Answer to mention your specific example.

Comment: @BasilBourque for Europe/Moscow the difference is P5M3D, not P5M5D. This is because the "then" date is one day later in Moscow than in Guernsey (2am vs 11pm). You probably got P5M5D because you calculated "today" the day after the question was asked.

Comment: @BasilBourque by the way, I'm not sure it's correct to say "such calculation is *always* dependent on time zone". It's only when you discard the time from both days. Then the calculation depends on time zones due to "rounding errors", in the same way that the integer interval between 1.9 and 2.1 is 1 if you first discard the fractional parts from both numbers, and 0 if you don't. If you don't first discard the times from both dates before calculating the period, then the calculation is probably independent of time zone.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException The calculation is *always* dependent on time zone. If you (probably as opposed to the asker) want the period between the exact points in time, that may vary depending on transitions to and from summer time (DST), for example (and such transitions differ between time zones).

Comment: @OleV.V. ah, yes, those damn summer time transitions throwing a spanner in the works of what would otherwise have been a simple calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly spoken, you cannot because a so called "epoch time" is really an instant and NOT a duration. But you might want to model the elapsed time since that epoch (Unix epoch) as duration. So here you go:

```
System.out.println(Duration.of(1512431637067L, ChronoUnit.MILLIS));
// output: PT420119H53M57.067S
```

The method `java.time.Duration.toString()` automatically normalizes the seconds and nanoseconds to HMS-format (otherwise we have to state that the printing capabilities of the new duration class are limited). If you wish more control over ISO-format then either consider your own workaround using methods like `toHours()` etc. or use a 3rd-party-library for duration printing.

Another thing: 1512431637067 seems to be in milliseconds not in seconds as you stated otherwise you would get an instant in far future:

```
System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochMilli(1512431637067L));
// output: 2017-12-04T23:53:57.067Z

System.out.println(Instant.ofEpochSecond(1512431637067L));
// far future: +49897-01-18T19:11:07Z
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to output the difference in Months and Days between the given Instant and the current clock time. `Duration.between(givenInstant, now)` but with months and days rather than total number of hours.

Answer (score 0):

try this line

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Date date=new Date (1512431637067L);
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX", Locale.US);
    System.out.print(df.format(date));
  }
}
```

output date on iso 8601:

`2017-12-04T23:53:57.067Z`

Comment: This is not a duration but an instant in old-fashioned style.

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: As Ole V.V. commented, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).